# Displaying Documenting Source Code in Sharepoint

Tags: development, documentation

I am looking for a way to display source code in SharePoint.

We are migrating from Mediawiki to SharePointand create there our new knowledge-database. With that our developers asked if we can provide them with a possibility to display source code.

The OOTB Text Webpart is not really configurable and I did not find any App which fulfills this purpose.

How are you people documenting source code, via SharePoint or are there other options?